# tf2 view_frames under namespace

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

env: ROS2 Galactic

how can I view the frames of a name-spaced simulation ? the command ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames does not work when I set a namespace.

[image: image description]

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404457/tf2-view_frames-under-namespace/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2022-07-31

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [igrak34](https://answers.ros.org/users/109560/igrak34/) on 2022-08-21**:
I'm interested as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've checked the package code and figure out that the command should be run like this:

ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot1 -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static

Where "robot1" is the targeted namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) with karma: 195 on 2022-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an answer, that is not nice, but works.

Go to `/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tf2_ros/transform_listener.py` and edit line 73 and 75 to your namespace. (Or search it via an IDE from /opt/ros/foxy/lib/tf2_tools/view_frames.py :line 45)

```
self.tf_sub = node.create_subscription(
            TFMessage, 'namespace/tf', self.callback, qos, callback_group=self.group)
        self.tf_static_sub = node.create_subscription(
            TFMessage, 'namespace/tf_static', self.static_callback, static_qos, callback_group=self.group)
```

Hope it works in your distribution as well and helps.

---

Originally posted by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) with karma: 105 on 2022-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2022-08-30**:
Thanks @zechurbo, I've posted a cleaner solution.